# Name to distinguish between parameters used for 'is not equal' operations and those used for 'is equal' operations

Tags: nouns, terminology

I am writing a dating website (for example) which allows a person to search for partners matching certain features. i.e "non-blondes in New York".

I am having trouble trying to find the perfect words to use that distinguish between:

- search criteria that is used for queries like ( location *is equal to* New York )
- search criteria that is used for queries like ( hair colour *is not equal to* blonde )

I am not necessarily looking for purely academic words - because they may not be understood by the general population. Despite that, academic words may end up being the best choice.

Any suggestions?

I have suggested some answers and would be interested to see which are the most sensible choice of words.

Feel free to add extra suggestions. There are probably some really obvious ones that I cannot see from the perspective of the mental trench that I'm sitting in.

- **equasive** Criteria
- **inequasive** Criteria

---

- **positive** Criteria
- **negative** Criteria

---

- **additive** Criteria
- **subtractive** Criteria

---

Comment: You may find you get more traction by placing "possible answers" within the body of your question, or as a comment below, and allow the respondents to populate answers based on the information you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to wedge the meanings into adjectives that just aren't natural.  I would suggest variations like:

Criteria that are **required**  (i.e. **requirements**).  Colloquially, you might say **must-haves**.

And criteria that are **disallowed** or **prohibited** (i.e. **prohibitions**)  Colloquially a common term in the context of dating would be **dealbreakers**.

Comment: or turn-ons vs turn-offs

Comment: 'Must-haves' and 'Deal breakers' are words that I would never have thought of, but make a lot of sense. So, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

- **inclusive** Criteria
- **exclusive** Criteria

Comment: Depending on your context using the words "including" and "excluding" will work too.

Answer (score 1):

You may use **cover/include** for "is equal to" and **exclude/excluding** for "is not equal to" E.g:

> location covering/covers  New York.
>
> location  including/includes New York.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the tone of the site, "must have" or "never use" could also be options. You will probably need to select different words for different types of criteria.

Location: within "x" mi of New York
Hair: [must be] Blonde
Age: younger than 35

By tailoring these inclusion/exclusion criteria to the type of information you're trying to collect the wording will be much more clear for your clients.